# MediaWiki installation script does not create tables

Tags: php, postgresql, mediawiki, unix-socket

First - I'm not sure if that's the correct place to post my question hence if I'm wrong doing it here please just let me know and I'll re-post somewhere else.
Also I spent whole weekend trying to find out answer to my question with google - no luck.

I'm trying to get MediaWiki working on my server. I wanted to have it working with postgresql through UNIX sockets. I store my socket under /run and I used to connect to database through PHP typing something like this:

```
 $db_connection = pg_connect("host='/run' user='user_name' password='some_password' dbname='database_name');
```

So when configuring MediaWiki through their installation script I just typed '/run' into 'server' input box hoping it will plug it into connection string. So everything works fine until I reach last step (where script actually does all the work) and I get an information that tables are created with last entry showing an error when trying to write into database. So I connected to database using psql and found no tables created by the script...

That's what I get when installation script terminates:

```
Could not insert main page: A database error has occurred. Did you forget to run maintenance/update.php after upgrading? See: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Run_the_update_script Query: SELECT nextval('externallinks_el_id_seq') Function: DatabaseBase::query Error: 42P01 ERROR: relation "externallinks_el_id_seq" does not exist LINE 1: .../* DatabaseBase::query 188.220.126.122 */ nextval('externall... ^
```

So here is the question - have anybody ever used MediaWiki with postgresql through UNIX socket? If so then may I kindly ask how to feed that information into MediaWiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into my http stack setup I noticed my permissions have been too restricted. After relaxing them and allowing 'others' group to read 'wikimedia' directory things seem to be working as they should. I'm not sure if that's 'proper' solution to that problem and would appreciate if anybody would come up with better idea however for the time being my issue is solved.

To finish out it might be important that even though I'm using UNIX socket I still left default port value untouched.